# Train fastai tabular_learner on new data

Tags: python, deep-learning, fast-ai

dls = TabularDataLoaders.from_df(df, '.', procs=procs, cat_names=cat_names, cont_names=cont_names,
y_names="won",valid_idx=list(range(int(len(df)*0.8),len(df))), bs=64)
learn = tabular_learner(dls)
learn.fit(20)

I want to train the "learn" model on new data (df2). Normally I would just combine both dataframes in one and train the model, but I can't due to memory issues .. so how can I continue training the model but in df2 instead of the original df ?

Answer (score 0):

Does reducing your batch size help with memory issues? E.g. in this example below, I set bs=8

```
dls = TabularDataLoaders.from_df(df, '.', procs=procs, cat_names=cat_names, 
cont_names=cont_names,y_names="won",valid_idx=list(range(int(len(df)*0.8),len(df))), bs=8)
learn = tabular_learner(dls) learn.fit(20)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't even read the combined dataframes without running out of memory (20 Gb data combined).